# blizzard (snowstorm driven by strong, sustained winds)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This word first used, it seems, in 1859, is different from a snowstorm in that it indicates “ a strong, sustained storm of wind and cold, and dry, driving snow”. The only word I can find in Latin is ningor in Apuleius’s De Mundo, 9:- Haec cum, victis nubibus, crebrior ad terram venit, eam nos tempestatem ningorem vocamus.
The context here does not seem to imply ‘a strong sustained storm’. Would I have to add something like violentis impulsus ventis ningor?

Comment: But the English says "strong, sustained storm" not "strong, sustained wind."

Comment: Point taken. procella would’nt do since that is a squall. Perhaps then ningor violenta impulsus tempestate.

Comment: I need a moderatot to alter the title to ‘a strong sustained storm’

Comment: I think cmw is referring to ‘a strong sustained wind‘ in the body of the post, which *ningor* doesn't seem to imply; your title appears to be correct (except for a typo).—I went ahead and fixed both.

Comment: Thanks, Unbrutal Russian, on both counts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sī quidem *vim ventī cum pluviā **procellam*** [vocāmus](http://lexica.linguax.com/forc2.php?searchedLG=procella), licet istud *procellam niveam seu nivālem* dīcāmus. Atque hoc cōnferātur cum illō 'snowstorm' Anglicō quod idem fere quod 'blizzard' significat, aut cum eijusdem generis vīcīnitāte inter ea vocābula Rūssica quae sunt 'сне́жная бу́ря' et ['мете́ль'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blizzard). Sī apud antīquōs auctōrem quaerimus, [ēn Curtius](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/860/1/12/1805-1820#12), *“procella”* ait *“subitō nivem effūderat.”* Hinc appāret vel sine adjectīvō ūsurpārī posse.

Praetereā [inveniō](http://lexica.linguax.com/forc2.php?searchedLG=hiems) ***hiemem*** pōnī prō omnī genere malae tempestātis (“Hiems dicitur de vento, pluvia et procellis, *tempesta, procella:* quam et Graeci *χειμῶνα* dicunt.”). Et hoc vocābulum Latīnum dē nivālī tempestāte nōn inveniō, [Graecum tamen illud](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BC%CF%8E%CE%BD) ita admodum ūsurpārī vidētur. Hanc itaque differentiam ipsīus caelī dissimilitūdinī tribuāmus velim, et *hiemem* prō procellā niveā pōnere nōn metuam, fortasse vōce quādam appositā, ut *atrōx, vehemens, rapida, multa,* quālia fere ventīs junguntur.

*ning(u)or* autem nihil aliud sibi velle vidētur quam 'snowfall, [снегопад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4)'. Quod vocābulum licet apud Aureōs auctōrēs nōn inveniātur, tamen crēdō id fierī proptereā quod ipsīus rei dēscrībendae rārior fuit occāsiō, nōn quod plānē vocābulum improbārint. Namque saepe sōlā *nive* contentī fuērunt; similiter et Anglicē 'snow' prō 'snowfall' saepe sufficit. Vērum et hoc aliquandō ūsuī·st, praesertim sī maijōrem cōpiam nivis significāre necesse·st, quae quidem rēs aliīs plagīs frequentius accidit quam aliīs; et procellās niveās complectī vidētur pariter ac lēniōrem caelum. Quippe et Āpuleijus 'vocāmus' dīxit, ergō in ōribus fuit, per analogiam *frīgēre > frīgus, frangere > frāgor* fictum.

Comment: in errorem inductus sum (proh dolor!) parvo lexico vetusto in quo sub titulo ‘snowstorm’ ‘ningor/ ninguor’ datus est. ipsa vocabuli raritas ‘ningor’ me monere debuit. ‘ningor’, ut nunc intellexi, est vocabulum quod Latinorum auctorum Aevi Aurei aures respuerent, cum ipsis in thesauro verborum praesto essent ea vocabula quae in responso tuo praebuisti, mi Scytha, neglectis alienis vocabulis. me praecipue delectant cum exempla tua, tum dicta de usu hiemis, additis adiectivis propriis. ad summam, responsum viridi avicula dignum.

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Nunc intelligō mē aliquid et dē istō vocābulō dīcere dēbuisse! nam plānē respuendum equidem nōn dūcō, neque dīxerim id apud Aetātis Aureae aureōs auctōrēs proptereā nōn invenīrī quod plānē respuerint, vērum ipsam rem rārius dēscrībendam illīs fuisse. namque saepe sōlā *nive* contentī fuērunt; similiter et Anglicē 'snow' prō 'snowfall' saepe sufficit; neque *ninguor* aliud sibi velle vidētur quam 'snowfall, [снегопад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Снегопад)'. vērum et hoc aliquandō ūsuī·st, praesertim sī maijōrem cōpiam nivis significāre necesse·st. quippe et 'vocāmus' dīxit!

Comment: Haec, putō, et responsō meō adiciam quō rem accūrātius explōrātam faciam, ut magis et tibi, benigne Jōhanne, serviat et lēctōrī futūrō!

Comment: de adnotationibus tuis te multum te amo, mi Scytha. post quas adiectas,  inveni apud Lucretium vocabulum ‘ningues’ et apud Livium  ‘casus nivis.’ tamen alii editores legunt ‘nives’ pro ‘ningues’. fortasse hic difficilior lectio potior. illius lectionis autem veri simile te non inscium esse. sus Minervam!

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Immō istud vocābulum ignōrāveram! eam autem lēctiōnem [jam Servius trādit](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=ningue); adeō et carminis numerīs *ninguēs* tantum convenit. et hoc *ninguēs* rem indicat, particulās nivis sīve aggerem eijusdem; illud *ninguor* vērō ninguendī āctiōnem, nivis nempe cāsum, quae jūnctūra [etiam apud Plīnium](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23casu+~+%23nivi) legitur. cēterum invicem tē amō quod haec scrībis eōque ecficis ut rem suptīlius explōrandō ūnā discāmus!

Comment: mi Scytha, multas tibi gratias ago quod in omnibus responsis tuis videris omnes optiones amplecti et quidem, quod ad me pertinet conata mea, quamvis levia videantur, magni aestimare atque in serium convertere. praeterea, omnes in hoc situ collatores  semper colis observantia et tractas honore. – 
Jonathan Hadfield
 56 mins ago   Delete